# Not at home after login

Tags: bash, login, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2. I expect that the bash shall be started in the home directory that I find in /etc/passwd as

```
harper:x.1000:1000:,,,,:/home/harper:/bin/bash
```

But after starting `wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04` the bash is somewhere in the Windows tree: `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32`. I only need to issue the `cd` command to get into home. And I could add this in a last line of ~/.bashrc. I already checked that this file is executed while starting bash.

But why do I see this strange behavior that the home directory is not the current directory?

**Edit:** I have also found a workaround. I can start `wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04 --cd ~`. But this doesn't explain, why it's necessary.

Comment: That is likely related to the tool `wsl`, not to the Ubuntu system. You indeed can adjust the command line of the tool to land in the directory you want as you found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command `wsl -d Distro` will always land you on the windows directory you ran the command from. If you want to start at home, you can either specify it in the same command:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04 --cd ~
```

Or use the distro's executable:

```
ubuntu2204.exe
```